# Why is it saying my list is a tuple when I try to append?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to append something to an empty list but and error comes up saying that it doesn't not work on a tuple although it is a list.

Here is the code

```
l = []
u = [31536000, 86400, 3600, 60]
z = 157310805

for i in u:
    l.append(z), z %= i
```

the error says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/default/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from solution import format_duration
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 10
    l.append(z), z %= i
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'tuple' is an illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

Comment: The comma operator creates a tuple. What are you trying to do by putting `, z %= i` on the same line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, using a [site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+comma+tuples), there's the fairly closely related questions of [python tuple ending with comma difference](/q/66176774), [Unintentional trailing comma that creates a tuple](/q/44700951), [Why is a tuple of tuples of length 1 not actually a tuple unless I add a comma?](/q/31293862), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a tuple by putting `z %= i` on the same line, separated with `,`. This is an invalid statement because an assignment can't be used as an expression in a tuple.

You should put each statement on its own line.

```
for i in u:
    l.append(z)
    z %= i
```

If you *really* need to put multiple statements on the same line, you can use `;` to separate them.

```
for i in u:
    l.append(z); z %= i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
u = [31536000, 86400, 3600, 60]
z = 157310805

for i in u:
    l.append(z)
    z %= i
```

The problem here isn't really about tuples, it's just getting confused about the comma. The solution is to break into a new line.